Best way to design screen flow reactivity with LWC outputs on the same page
I have created a LWC that acts as a top-level filter for user's to choose different properties and filter data based on their selected inputs. Multiple screen flows and LWCs need to be able to react to these changes and display filtered data accordingly. This will be happening on an experience site.
My filter component is saving user selections as a custom setting in order to manage state. I'm currently embedding this filter within single Lightning Web Component pages, but the solution needs to expand to pages containing multiple screen flows and LWCs. Is it possible to achieve this level of reactivity between LWC and screen flows on the same page? Documentation doesn't indicate LMS usage within screen flows

I'm not sure how your flow is embeded in lwc page but you can put an lwc inside flow which can react to LMS. Or you could read the custom settings value when the flow is executed to get the updated filters.
